# How do I penalize (downward boost) in solr?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I need to do three things and I'm just not able to figure this out:

1. penalize a missing facet (say "brand") in a search query. I tried doing *&defType=dismax&qf=(*:* AND -brand:[* TO *])^1000* but it is penalizing all results
2. up or down boost a particular facet if it contains a particular string **irrespective** of what the query was - for example I want to up-boost any result containing free/freebi/freebie in the title string and down-boost any result containing "pre-used" in the title string
   I tried doing  *&defType=dismax&qf=(title:[FREEBIES OR FREE])^1000* but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

`fq=<YOUR MAIN QUERY>&bq=(-brand:[* TO x])^9999`

Comment: no - here is my parsed query "querystring":"'canon slr'",
  "parsedquery":"+((DisjunctionMaxQuery((body:canon^0.3 | author:canon^100.0 | title:canon^1000.0 | model:canon^100.0 | category:canon^50.0 | name:canon^3.0 | brand:'canon^20.0)~0.01) DisjunctionMaxQuery((body:slr^0.3 | author:slr^100.0 | title:slr^1000.0 | model:slr^100.0 | category:slr^50.0 | name:slr^3.0 | brand:slr'^20.0)~0.01))~2) DisjunctionMaxQuery((body:\"canon slr\"~15^2.0)~0.01) ((-brand:[* TO canon])^9999.0) FunctionQuery(1000.0/(1.0*float(top(rord(created)))+1000.0))",